# 500 seats, how many visits before it is more likely than not that you will sit on the same seat as for one of your earlier visits?

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations

**A theatre has 500 seats and you buy tickets randomly. How many times do you need to visit the theatre before it is more likely than not that you will sit on the same seat as for one of your earlier visits?**

Comment: compare with birthday paradoxon

Comment: Can the formula 500!/500^n(500-n)! therefore be used?

Comment: Perhaps surprisingly, in an ordinary install of R this would be `qbirthday(classes=500)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the first $n$ for which $$\frac{500!}{500^n(500-n)!}<\frac{1}{2}.$$